# how to monitor a Heroku postgres database

Tags: postgresql, heroku, database-performance, newrelic

NewRelic gives nice database analyses, however it seems to track only the web app's transactions.

I have independently managed servers which query and load my Heroku postgresql database. Is there a way I can get diagnostics and analysis of the database activity so that it will include all connections to it?

Answer (score 4):

New Relic application monitoring will only collect data on database queries that are part of a web transaction or background task that is being monitored. If you're using one of New Relic's supported languages to query your database, you may be able to track that code as a background task (see https://newrelic.com/docs/features/monitoring-background-processes). If you would like a general monitoring plugin for your postgresql database, you could check out the postgresql plugin for New Relic (created and supported by Boundless): http://newrelic.com/plugins/boundless/109.

Answer (score 1):

You should also try Heroku PG Extras: https://github.com/heroku/heroku-pg-extras. That will give info about cache hit, indexes, long queries, etc.